# Small, mobile Bing Maps zooms into Tschad for given LocationRect bounds

Tags: bing-maps

I have the problem that my Bing Maps should zoom to the given Locations. So I calculate the LocationRect with [fromLocations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712644.aspx), then I pass this to the Map. This works for all medium/bigger displays but does not work for smaller width like you find on mobiles.

I created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nachtigall/pen/gmLbGX) where one can see this. In the end both create a map with (but the result is different):

```
  var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($map[0], {
    // credentials: apikey,
    enableClickableLogo: false,
    bounds: getBounds()
  });
```

Is this a Bing Maps bug? Any ideas for workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with large LocationRect's. There is a fix in the works for this and it should be in the experimental branch in the next month or two.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a open bug tracker, say, like there is bugzilla.mozilla.org? Because since it is a known bug, it would have been great to know about it beforehand and would have save my time debugging our app into which I digged first of course :-/

Comment: Not a public one. If you have a Bing Maps license you can contact the Bing Maps Enterprise support team and they can provide the bug number and updates.